# SpringBoot Cacheable unless result with List

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I've read that `#result` always refers to the business entity and never on a supported wrapper.

Does it means that the following case below won't work?

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames="book", unless="#result?.size() > 0")
public List<Book> findBook(String name)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would still work. The [SpEL documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) shows that Lists (and arrays) are identified by the language. So the "business entity" in this case is the "List of books". If instead, you want to apply a condition on each of the books, you can do:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames="book", unless="#result?.[#this.pages() > 50]") 
public List<Book> findBook(String name)
```