# How to cache with condition on result object in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I want to cache the result in spring boot with condition on the result.

```
@Cacheable(value = "saveCache", key = "{#a, #b, #c}")
public Response save(String a, String b, String c) {
  // block of code
  List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList();

  new Response(result)
}
```

In the above code, I want to cache only if response.result is not empty. I have tried the below method, but it doesn't work for me

```
@Cacheable(value = "saveCache", key = "{#a, #b, #c}", unless="#result.result == null")

@Cacheable(value = "saveCache", key = "{#a, #b, #c}", unless="#result.result.size > 0")
```

> [Error] EL1008E: Property or field 'size' cannot be found on object of
> type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?

```
@Cacheable(value = "saveCache", key = "{#a, #b, #c}", unless="#result.result.length > 0")
```

> [Error] EL1008E: Property or field 'length' cannot be found on object
> of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?

Answer (score 2):

As size is a method of ArrayList. Please use it like this.

```
@Cacheable(value = "saveCache", key = "{#a, #b, #c}", unless="#result.result.size() > 0")
```

For ref:
[SpringBoot Cacheable unless result with List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035795/springboot-cacheable-unless-result-with-list)